# Default release lint vs. gradle lint task

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

By default lint is enabled for release builds in gradle. Without the

```
abortOnError false
```

option this aborts a build.

My release build executes successfully (without lint warnings), but when I call the **lintRelease** task via gradle it fails with 3 errors and 222 warnings.

Further more, if I use the "*Analyse*"-"*Inspect code...*" functionality from the Android Studio menu I even get a different result.

Why do these approaches behave differently and whats the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

*'Inspect code'*, as an IDE feature, uses not only android lint to perform a code checkup, but also many other custom actions (searching for infinite loops, code styling, suggesting replacing anonymous types with lambdas etc.).

From experience, mine and many other developers', it is almost impossible to deploy a production app without lint warnings.

Comment: Ok that makes sense for the Android Studio part, but what exactly is the difference between running the lint gradle task and the implicit execution during a release build and why does it produce different results?

Comment: Hmm I don't know yet, maybe instead of abortOnError you will try following: lintOptions { checkReleaseBuilds false } and let know if it works and maybe we will figure something out